# How to Configure Appium on Mac OS?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium

Hi I have issues configuring and using Appium on Mac. Can you recommend some detailed step by step manual. I can not figure out all required steps. My problem is that I need quickly set up working environment.

I installed Appium app. I configured server and started it. I don't see Appium session when try inspector. Also in my Appium App I can not run Appium-doctor, even I install it using terminal.

I still not figure out where I have to use Appium Java client and Selenium stand-alone server.

*EDIT:* I executed following steps.

1. Installed Appium dmg
2. Create .ipa
3. Point that .ipa path in iOS config in Appium
4. Uploaded app to iOS simulator.
5. Set simulator UDID
6. Start Server
7. I see status 200 in the log
8. Wehn I try to use inspector it give me error: "Could not launch Appium inspector". In the log - "could not initialize ideviceinstaller;"

Comment: add Error message here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
--device-name "iPhone 6 (8DB01BD3-E974-4BA6-AB40-50182BFD8800)"
```

with

```
--device-name "iPhone 6"
```

In Appium GUI from in list "iPhone 6 (8DB01BD3-E974-4BA6-AB40-50182BFD8800) (8.1 Simulator)" remove all text except "iPhone 6" and try again (valid for MAC GUI).

Comment: the OPs issue is with the Appium driver that is loaded on the phone not connecting to the phone

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If you have installed jDK/XCODE prior to installing appium. Here are the steps that you need to follow.

1. [Install Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. Configure JAVA HOME

   export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
3. Install XCODE
4. Install android SDK
5. Configure ANDROID HOME
6. Install Appium

Here is the step by step guide for all above steps. [Appium Download &Installation](http://www.testautomationsimplified.com/appium-tutorial/appium-download-osx/).

Comment: You need to compile your app in xcode and install it in simulator before using it in appium.

Comment: Hi, 10x for replay. I already have xcode installed. I also install command tools using a command from the internet. I have JAVA (I also updated it). I did not configure Android because at first this environment will be used for tesing iOS. I will check the link, you provided.

Comment: can you please share java code? I would like to see capabilities you are using.

Comment: I did not have yet Java code. I first try to open [Inspector] function. I unserdtand where was my problem. I set reset configuration, but I have some problem with target and after Appium removes app and try to reinstall it - it can not do that, @abhijeet kanade.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have the Appium inspector app signed by your organisations IOS development keys for it to automate your app.

The basics are that you need to find the Xcode package in appium's node_modules folder and open it Xcode then sign it

I would suggest pairing with an IOS developer to get this setup , its quite tricky and depending on your org structure there are different ways to do this.